# sed replace with exception list

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I need to replace strings in many large textfiles but I have a list of exception strings (200+ items). For example:

```
# I want to replace every "dank". Except when it comes in the following form:
 
dankine
dankzwd
nudankip
dankphys
danko.mod
... (The list is 200+ items long)
```

My current regex looks like this:

```
sed -e "s/dank/monk/g" /path/to/file
```

The content of the file looks like this:

```
xdankine redankus
dankzwd 
danke dankbe
testdank
```

this is the content of the file after execution:

```
xmonkine remonkus
monkzwd 
monke monkbe
testmonk
```

But I want the content to look like this:

```
xdankine remonkus
dankzwd 
monke monkbe
testmonk
```

since dankine and dankzwd are in my exclusion list.

The file can contain more than one possible replacement per line.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: If it's always surrounded by spaces, you can change the pattern to `s/ dank / monk /` - or use character classes (`\s` for whitespace especially)

Comment: @Panki Unfortunatly  it is not alway surrounded by spaces.

Comment: Another question occurred about what you expect for `dankdank` if `dankda` is in the exclusion list: 1) The whole `dankda` is protected, so it needs to stay `dankdank`. 2) The `dankda` protects only the `dank`, but not the `da`, so it can become `dankmonk`. 3) After the second `dank` of 2 has been replaced the first one is not protected anymore and it shall be `monkmonk`. 4) You don't care at all.

Comment: @Philippos Case 1) should be the exptected behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as not to overload the regex since the exclusion list can be 200+ strong, we first generate the sed code using the exclusion list file and apply that generated code on the data input.

GNU sed

```
sed -e '
  1i\
s/dank/\\n/g
  h;s:[\&/]:\\&:g
  x;s/dank/\n/g
  s:[][^$\/.*]:\\&:g
  s/\n/\\n/g;G
  s:\n:/:;s:.*:s/&/g:
  $a\
s/\\n/MONK/g
' excludes.txt | sed -f - file
```

---

Output:-

```
xdankine reMONKus
dankzwd
MONKe MONKbe
testMONK
```

---

Proof of concept:-

- First off, turn all danks to literal newlines, a char guaranteed not to be found.
- Then turn a line in exclude list like `nudankip` to as given below and likewise for all lines in exclude list.
- `s/nu\nip/nudankip/g`
- The complexity is due to the fact that we need to escape the exclude list fir the rhs and lhs of a sed s/// expression.

Comment: That doesn't work if you have for instance `dankda` as an exclusion and `dankdank` in the input (in which case you get `MONKMONK` instead of `dankMONK`)

Comment: Please note that using `\n` for newline in the replacement is not POSIX and will fail with most `sed` implementations. It will work for GNU `sed`, however.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to expand the sed with with a second regex? Like a second -e ?

Comment: @Jan yes you can add multiple -e

Comment: @Stephane you are correct but since the OP hadn't given any indications of such inputs and what heuristics to choose in getting the output so I refrained from going there.

Comment: @Phillipos you are right a noting about it is required.

Comment: There is a standard alternative to GNU's `\n` in RHS though: `\<newline>` instead.

Answer (score 4):

If you have only one occurences of `dank` per line like in your example, you can use inverted addresses:

```
sed -E '/dankine|dankzwd|nudankip|dankphys|danko\.mod/!s/dank/monk/'
```

If there can be multiple occurences per line, you could use a character which can't be part of the file, e. g. `#`, change all `dank` to `#`, change back for the word list and change `#` to `monk` for the rest:

```
sed 's/dank/#/g;s/#ine/dankine/g;s/#zwd/dankzwd/g;s/nu#ip/nudankip/g;s/#phys/dankphys/g;s/#o\.mod/danko.mod/g;s/#/monk/g'
```

(If any character can occur, use a newline instead)

**Update: New requirement to read the exclusion list from a file**

Write your blacklist to the file `exclusion.list` *with a trailing newline* (the script will use this to detect where the first file ends):

```
sed -e '1,/^$/{H;d;}' -e 'G;s/\n/&&/;:loop' -e 's/\(.*da\)\(nk.*\)\(.*\n\1\2\n\)/\1#\2\3/;tloop' -e 's/\n.*//;s/dank/monk/g;s/da#nk/dank/g' exclusion.list file
```

or, as multiline perhaps easier to read

```
sed '1,/^$/{H;d;}
  G
  s/\n/&&/
  :loop
  s/\(.*da\)\(nk.*\)\(.*\n\1\2\n\)/\1#\2\3/
  tloop
  s/\n.*//
  s/dank/monk/g
  s/da#nk/dank/g' exclusion.list file
```

Anyhow, this may still be easier to write than to read. The concept is

- Read the exclusion list to hold space
- For each line of the file append that list in the hold space
- Replace each `dank` in the file which appears in the list by `da#nk` to prevent it from being replaced later
- Then remove the list, replace all `dank` by `monk` and finally remove the `#` from the `da#nk`s.

Adding `l` after the `:loop` illustrates the working principle.

Thanks to Stéphane for hinting the `dankfoodank` problem, which is solved here. The requirement for `dankdank` case however remains unclear Should it be `dankmonk` because only the `dank` of `dankda` is protected or should it remain `dankdank` because the `da` of the second `dank` is protected as being a part of `dankda` or is this out of scope?

Comment: @Jan that is the sort of thing you need to mention in the question so we don't waste our time and yours providing solutions that won't help you. Please edit your question and make sure all of your requirements are listed.

Comment: That doesn't work if for instance you have both `foodank` and `dankfoo` as exclusions and `dankfoodank` in the input. Also if there's a `dankda` exclusion and `dankdank` in the input like with @guest_7's answer.

Comment: Thanks, @StéphaneChazelas I addressed the `dankfoodank` case in my update, but I'm not sure about the right handling of the `dankdank` case.

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box and using literal string operations so we don't care about any regexp or backreference metachars in the input or exceptions list:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    mask[$0] = RS NR RS
    next
}
{
    delete changed
    for (exception in mask) {
        while ( s=index($0,exception) ) {
            $0 = substr($0,1,s-1) mask[exception] substr($0,s+length(exception))
            changed[exception]
        }
    }

    gsub(/dank/,"monk")

    for (exception in changed) {
        while ( s=index($0,mask[exception]) ) {
            $0 = substr($0,1,s-1) exception substr($0,s+length(mask[exception]))
        }
    }

    print
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk exceptions file
xdankine remonkus
dankzwd
monke monkbe
testmonk
```

The above assumes you don't have exceptions that are substrings of other exceptions like `dankfoo` and `dankdankfoo` since you don't show cases like that in the example in your question. If you do then make sure the exceptions file is sorted such that the longer superstrings come before the shorter substrings and iterate on them in the order they were input so you don't replace `xdankdankfooy` with `xdank<replacement>y` instead of `x<replacement>y` when masking the exceptions in the first loop.

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`, you could do:

```
perl -pe '
  BEGIN{
    chomp (@excl = <STDIN>);
    $re = "(" . join( "|", map {qr{\Q$_\E}} @excl) . ")|dank"
  }
  s{$re}{$1//"monk"}ge' input < exclusion.list
```

That constructs a regexp such as:

```
(dankine|dankzwd|nudankip|dankphys|danko\.mod)|dank
```

And we replace any occurrence of it with either `$1` (so what was matched, so essentially doing nothing) if `$1` is set (one of the exclusions was matched) or `monk` otherwise (`dank` was matched instead).

Note that if the exclusions include both `dankzwd` and `zwddank`, that will still turn `dankzwddank` into `dankzwdmonk` as it replaces `dankzwd` with `dankzwd` (`$1`) first, and then only `dank` is left for it to replace.

An approach to address that would be to record all the places where any exclusion occurs in a mask string, and then when it comes to replace `dank`, only do the replacement where the mask says it's fine.

```
perl -spe '
  BEGIN {
    chomp (@excl = <STDIN>);
    $word_len = length $word;
  }
  my $len = length;
  my $mask = "-" x $len;
  my $i;
  for my $e (@excl) {
    my $e_len = length $e;
    my $hide = "#" x $e_len;
    for (my $o = 0;
         $o < $len && ($i = index($_, $e, $o)) >= 0;
         $o = $i + 1) {
      substr($mask, $i, $e_len) = $hide;
    }
  }
  s{dank}{substr($mask, pos, $word_len) =~ /-/ ? $repl : $&}ge
  ' -- -word=dank -repl=monk input < exclusion.list
```

So for instance, if an input line contains:

```
dodankdankdankoodankdodank
```

and the exclusions have: `dankdank`, `dankdo` the mask would be built progressively from

```
 --------------------------
 --########---------------- # first dankdank
 --############------------ # second dankdank
 --############--######---- # first and only dankdo
 dodankdankdankoodankdodank
                       ^^^^
```

Then that leaves only the `dank` at the end that is not affected by exclusions.